# How to classify land use change

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-classification

I’m trying to classify land use change in Google Earth Engine. The classification is made by using pins to assign different reflectance indexes to different land use types. However, when I change the time period (year) studied the pinned land use may change and the engine then classify the land use incorrectly.

I currently use the following code to create the map that is classified:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_L2')
.filterDate('1994-01-01', '2001-12-31')
.filterBounds(region)
.filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than', 100)
.map(f_cloudMask_landsat)`
.map(applyScaleFactors)`
.map(addNDVI);
print(dataset);
```

However, I believe I need to create two maps, one static (set to a specific time period) where the classification of the reflectances is made and one where I change the time and use the classification to avoid this problem. Is this correct and does anybody know how I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can train your classifier with training data from one image and then use it to classify both images. The below is a very quick example, just to get the idea across. You do have to be careful when doing this though. Errors in the classification, for instance due to cloud and haze, will compound when combining classifications like this.

One thing you can consider it to use the probability that the classifications are correct and exclude changes with high uncertainty.

```
var referenceData = forest.merge(nonForest)
var trainingData = from.sampleRegions({
  collection: referenceData, 
  scale: 10
})
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(5)
  .train({
    features: trainingData, 
    classProperty: 'class'
  })
var fromClassification = from.classify(classifier)
var toClassification = to.classify(classifier)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/93d7b0559f9872173fa88cf1c3b23c25